# Combine text alignment

Tags: text, page-layout, alignment

I am working on a multi-page report that has several different sections.

Due to text available, some of the sections are left aligned while other sections are full justified.

Is it acceptable to use mixed alignment of different sections in the same document?

Here is a sample image that has two different sections with different text alignment...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am unaware of any hard-and-fast "rules" of alignment that would prevent this usage.

My own personal document design and layout guidelines revolve around what looks good, is legible and navigable, what fits within the specific style of the given publication, and to some extent whether said publication's style is intentionally cribbing from past or present graphic and typographic design movements (de Stijl, Bauhaus, Isotype, International Typographic, 80's Memphis and so on) and what either fits within *or* ***intentionally*** breaks with convention / history of said publication and/or topic area.

From what I see in your two posted images, I'd not have any internal struggle with the mixture of alignments, assuming they are kept, as you have so far, separated at the least by page, and ideally IMHO by spread (assuming facing pages) though I suggest care and attention to tracking, spacing and kerning on the second paragraph of the page having the full justification - looks a bit too loose to my eye at a quick glance.

Hope that helps.